# What is a "closed subspace" of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I was reading a proof online and it linked to a book by Munkres which says

> Every *closed subspace* of a compact space is compact.

I dug out the book and searched the index for this term. Unfortunately it was not clearly defined, so I am assuming it just means its a subspace with closed sets in the topology? Because that's what the proof seems to imply and the word "closed subspace" conflicts with what I used to remember in linear algebra.

Comment: A closed subspace is a subspace that when treated as a subset of the original space is a closed set in the original topology. That is, if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, then $Y \subseteq X$ is a closed subspace of $X$ (When equipped with the subspace topology) when $X \setminus Y \in \tau$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A closed subspace is a subspace that when treated as a subset of the original space is a closed set in the original topology.

That is, if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, then $Y \subseteq X$ is a closed subspace of $X$ (When equipped with the subspace topology) when $X \setminus Y \in \tau$.

Similarly, if $Y \in \tau$, then $Y$ is an open subspace of $X$ when equipped with the subspace topology.

Comment: So in other words, if it happens that we define the topology on closed sets, then the "closed subspace" itself is part of the bigger topology?

Comment: If you define a topology to be the collection of closed sets, rather than the more common convention of the collection of open sets, then yes, the closed subspaces are simply the elements of the topology (With the subspace topology).

Comment: Ah okay, thanks; gotta wait 2 mins...