# What closed subspace definition is used here?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition, simplex, simplicial-complex

**Lemma 2.2** If $L$ is a subcomplex of $K$, then the polytope $\lvert L \rvert$ is a closed subspace of the polytope of $K$, denoted $\lvert K \rvert$. In particular, if $\sigma \in K$, then $\sigma$ is a closed subspace of $\lvert K \rvert$.

Proof: Suppose $A$ is closed in $\lvert L \rvert$. If $\sigma$ is a simplex of $K$, then $\sigma \cap \lvert L \rvert$ is the union of those faces $s_i$ of $\sigma$ that belong to $L$. Since $A$ is closed in $\lvert L \rvert$, the set $A \cap s_i$ is closed in $s_i$, and hence closed in $\sigma$. Since $A \cap \sigma$ is the finite union of the sets $A \cap s_i$, it is closed in $\sigma$. We conclude that $A$ is closed in $\lvert K \rvert$. Conversely, if $B$ is closed in $\lvert K \rvert$, then $B \cap \sigma$ for each $\sigma \in K$, and in particular for each $\sigma \in L$. Hence $B \cap \lvert L \rvert$ is closed in $\lvert L \rvert$.

I am using Elements of Algebraic Topology by Munkres and it does not give the definition of a closed subspace. It also does not appear to be using the definition here: [What is a "closed subspace" of a topological space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905585/what-is-a-closed-subspace-of-a-topological-space).

Comment: Why do you think Munkres is using a different definition of "closed subspace"?

Comment: It only appears to me that he is using something different because it is not immediately clear to me that he is using the same definition in the way he proved the theorem. Do you think he is using the same definition?

Comment: Yes, I think he's showing that $|L|$ is closed with respect to the weak topology in $|K|$ (more generally, he shows that any closed subspace of $|L|$ with respect to the topology of $|L|$ is also closed in $|K|$). He also shows in the last line that the subspace topology of $|L|$ coincides with the weak topology in $|L|$, so $|L|$ is naturally a subspace of $|K|$.

Comment: So $A$ is any subset of $\lvert L \rvert$ and following his argument, he has shown that for any simplex $\sigma \in K$, $\lvert L \rvert \cap \sigma$ is closed - a stated condition in the book for any set in $\lvert K \rvert$ to be closed in $\lvert K \rvert$. ...?

Comment: I have a follow up question. Why is it okay to say that $A \cap \sigma$ is a finite union of $A \cap s_i$? How do we know it is finite? Thank you very much.

Comment: $A$ is any *closed* subset of $|L|$. In particular, it works for $|L|$. So the answer to your first question is affirmative.

Comment: To the follow up question, I'm assuming $s_i$ stand for a (not necessarily top-dimensional) face of $\sigma$ and there are only finitely many faces in a simplex.

Comment: I do not remember reading that a simplex has only a finite number of faces. Hmmm...

Comment: Ahhh... it should be consequence of the finite dimension of a simplex. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it is a consequence of the definition of a face. A face of an  $n$-simplex consists of those points $(t_0,\dots, t_n)$ such that at least one $t_i=0$. There are only finitely many possibilities for that.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't have any more questions let me summarise everything in a proper answer.

Comment: No more questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up what we have said in the comments. Munkres is indeed using the same definition of a closed subspace, in this case, with respect to the weak topology: a subspace $C$ of $|K|$ is closed if and only if $C\cap \sigma$ is closed in $\sigma$ for every simplex $\sigma$ in $|K|$. So he shows that this is true for $|L|$ by showing it for every closed subspace $A$ of $|L|$ (in particlar, for $|L|$ itself).

In addition, in the last line he shows that the subspace topology of $|L|$ in $|K|$ is the same as the weak topology of $|L|$, so $|L|$ is naturally a subspace of $|K|$.

Finally, to also add the answer to your follow up question, $s_i$ stands for a (not necessarily top-dimensional) face of $\sigma$. Since a simplex has finitely many faces, then we can guarantee that there are finitely many $A\cap s_i$.

The reason why an $n$-simplex has finitely many faces is a consequence of the definition of a face. A face of an  $n$-simplex consists of those points $(t_0,\dots, t_n)$ such that at least one $t_i=0$. There are only finitely many possibilities for that.